# Aiogram Telegram удаление сообщений, содержащие ссылки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.entities != [] and message.chat.id)
async def delete_messages(message: types.Message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message_id)
            break
```

Попробовал так, но не хочет удаляться сообщение, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
Также, буду благодарен, если подскажете как сделать исключение. Чтобы с определенным доменом ссылки не удалялись (их будет несколько)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, в Ваш хэндлер ничего не приходит, попробуйте так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delete_messages(message: types.Message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            await message.delete()
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло